# Microstation launching into a blank window (no menus or anything)

Tags: vb6, microstation

We have a VB6 application here that automates the process of opening drawings and printing them with a specific printer that turns them into TIFF files.

I'm in the process of testing the application as we upgrade from V8 to V8i and I'm running into some problems just launching the application.

If I open the Microstation normally via the exe file everything works ok. But when I do:

```
Set msApp = CreateObject("MicrostationDGN.Application")
```

It opens a blank microstation window with no menus or anything (basically what the window looks like behind the file open dialog)

And then I do

```
msApp.OpenDesignFile ("dummy.dgn")
```

that looks like this: imgur.com/A5rc4.png

Is there something new with v8i where it doesn't bother loading the gui when opened as an object?

Comment: check references and try found MicrostationDGN. I never work with that but the problem is that no found it. It has sdk maybe you should setup if that is a dll copied to system32

Comment: Maybe this was a deliberate change by the authors. Have you thought of asking them?

Answer (score 0):

Did your application depends on some user preference of Microstation? I think you can debug your aplication step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the ustation.exe with the parameter -debug. This creates a file called debug.txt in the current working directory.
There you might find some helpful info.